# File Reader not keeping order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I'm doing a multi image upload component with preview and I have a problem that only happens sometimes with the piece of code that is doing the image preview.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.images.length > 0) {
      setPreview([]);
      for (const image of props.images) {
        if (image.type) {
          //fileChanger(props.images);
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            setPreview((prevState) => {
              return prevState.concat(reader.result)});
              //image.name
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(image);
        } else {
          setPreview((prevState) => prevState.concat(image));
        }
      }
    } else if (props.images === null) {
      //fileChanger(props.images);

      setPreview(null);
    }
  }, [props.images, fileChanger]);
```

The problem is that the images are not previwed in the same order as they are shown in the original array (props.images).
I think this might be due to the `reader.onloadend` taking longer with some images but I'm not sure and I'm looking for advice on a possible fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that problem is caused by `reader.onloadend` as thanks to it you are loading images in parallel asynchonously so it's not possible to guarantee order of triggered events.
If you need to have images in the same order as they were on input then you will have to introduce some synchronization.

Eg:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.images.length > 0) {
      setPreview([]);
    
      let toLoad = props.images.length;
      let loadedImages = [];

      let synchronizedPreview = (const ordinal, const image) => {
        loadedImages[ordinal] = image;
        if (--toLoad > 0) return;
        for (const loadedImage of loadedImages) {
          setPreview((prevState) => prevState.concat(loadedImage));
        }
      };

      let index = 0;
      for (const image of props.images) {
        const ordinal = index++;
        if (image.type) {
          //fileChanger(props.images);
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            synchronizedPreview(ordinal, reader.result);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(image);
        } else {
          synchronizedPreview(ordinal, image);
        }
      }

    } else if (props.images === null) {
      //fileChanger(props.images);

      setPreview(null);
    }
  }, [props.images, fileChanger]);
```

Comment: This code has a few problems when combined with mine as `image` is not defined because you are using `for (var i = 0; i < props.images.length; i++)` as a loop instead of the `for of` I had. I have adapted the code and it works, thank you. :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, JavaScript is not my cup of tea... :D Last time I touched it was 4 years ago, but thankfully you got the point.